# CORS - Enabled localhost origin on Azure API Management, but still receiving error

Tags: azure, axios, cors, create-react-app, azure-api-management

I'm trying to test retrieving data from my teams API that is configured via Azure API Management. I'm local hosting the client web app (a create-react-app project) that will be making calls to the API, and enabled CORS policies for my localhost origin in APIM.
I've added  the inbound policies for All Operations in APIM:
[image]

I call the api using the same headers and method that's enabled in the CORS policy.

[image]

Yet I still get hit with the "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
I don't want a use a plugin since that doesn't really solve the large problem, and I can't use a wildcard because 'Allow-Credentials' must be set to true.
I've looked at so many versions of this question and nothing has helped. Does anyone know what I might be missing?

Comment: If you change the allowed-headers to allow the wild card * does it work?

Comment: It does, but I need enable Allow-Credentials as well. I forgot to add that detail. I'll make an edit

Comment: Is there a preflight OPTIONS request sent? If yes, what's its result? You may need to add OPTIONS to the allowed methods ...

Comment: That was it! Thank you

Comment: Hi Jordyn, can you add more details of what headers you are passing in ? I'm getting the same error and I'm unable to resolve it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restating derpirscher's answer for others: I needed to add Options to the allowed method because a [preflight Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) request is sent:

```
<cors allow-credentials="true">
        <allowed-origins>
            <origin>http://localhost:3000</origin>
        </allowed-origins>
        <allowed-methods>
            <method>GET</method>
        </allowed-methods>
        <allowed-headers>
            <header>content-type</header>
            <header>accept</header>
            <header>authorization</header>
            <header>options</header>
        </allowed-headers>
</cors>
```

Comment: This did the trick for me!

Comment: @JustMe - What did you add in your policy after which it started working ?

Comment: Sorry, no markdown in comments, but this is my current policy. Not sure what I changed at the time tbh

```
<cors allow-credentials="true">
    <allowed-origins>
        <origin>https://yourwebsite.com</origin>
    </allowed-origins>
    <allowed-methods>
        <method>POST</method>
        <method>GET</method>
        <method>OPTIONS</method>
    </allowed-methods>
    <allowed-headers>
        <header>content-type</header>
        <header>accept</header>
        <header>authorization</header>
        <header>options</header>
    </allowed-headers>
</cors>
```

@Kumar

Comment: Thanks it started working for me when I added * from <header> Will keep digging into it more.